# jetpack compose viewModel() is giving error "has no zero argument constructor" with hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

In my project, compose viewModel() method is giving error "has no zero argument constructor" when I am using hilt.

```
@Composable
    fun HomeScreen(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()) {
    ...
    }
    
    @HiltViewModel
    class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) :
        ViewModel() {
    ...
    }
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class DataModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindRepository(
        fakePuppyRepository: RepositoryImpl
    ): Repository
}
```

these are my dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Comment: I also found this. But using `by viewModels()` in an activity works fine. Guessing it's a bug in one of the alpha libs.

Comment: Are you using this composable within NavHost? I am also running I to this problem and the Hilt integration page is outdated recommending HiltViewModelFactory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on your dependencies, I suspect you are using NavController/NavHost.

Add this dependency: [androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/hilt#1.0.0-alpha03)

Now in your composable which defines NavController, call HomeScreen as follows:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltNavGraphViewModel
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

...

@Composable
fun Main() {
  val navController = rememberNavController()
  NavHost(navController, startDestination = "home"){
    composable("home") {
      val model: HomeViewModel = hiltNavGraphViewModel(it)
      HomeScreen(model)
    }
  }
}

...
```

`hiltNavGraphViewModel(...)` can also be replaced with `viewModel(HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, backStackEntry))` (from https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2166#issuecomment-769162910)

Comment: I removed `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose` from the project based on this answer and I cannot believe that was the problem the whole time ‍♂️

Comment: In my case it was enough to add:
val exampleViewModel = hiltViewModel<ExampleViewModel>()
            ExampleScreen(exampleViewModel)

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation

Comment: I imagine that may be true now. This answer was very specific to androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha08 and androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha01. @Dương Minh answer may be more accurate now -- the key part is requiring the hilt-navigation-compose library

Answer (score 7):

The `hiltNavGraphViewModel()` extension has been deprecated. You can use `hiltViewModel()` instead if you use Navigation and Hilt.

First, add this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

And now you can use `hiltViewModel()` together with Navigation.

```
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
        composable("example") { backStackEntry ->
            // Creates a ViewModel from the current BackStackEntry
            // Available in the androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose artifact
            val exampleViewModel = hiltViewModel<ExampleViewModel>()
            ExampleScreen(exampleViewModel)
        }
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

More information: [Hilt and Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries?authuser=3#hilt-navigation)

Comment: Do you know how to scope the viewmodel to a nested graph?

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me when I set my ViewModel inside a package called **new**.

Let's say my base package is `com.example.appname`, I created a new pakage called new and I had `com.example.appname.new`, every other ViewModel factories were created successfully by Hilt with the exception the one inside of package **new**.

1. Rename the package with name **new**, it looks like it is reserved.
2. Move your ViewModel to another location.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Activity/Fragments which enclose the composables have `@AndroidEntryPoint` and you have the latest version of hilt dependencies.

Comment: This is a valid response as long as you don't use compose navigation and just want a simple activity-scoped viewmodel injection (as asked by OP).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in **Hilt version 2.44**, even though I had followed all the steps correctly.

```
@Composable
fun MainView(viewModel : MainViewModel = viewModel()) {
   ...
}
```

After checking the steps, finally found the problem:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MyTheme {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

If you **stop previewing** the Composable function that has the ViewModel, the error will be fixed.

I hope this strange problem will be solved soon!

Answer (score -1):

I solved my error after renaming my package name `...ui.screens.main.new` which contains my class `MyCustomViewModel` inside the `new: package`. before renaming the `new` package to `addnew` my problem was solved.